# Не срабатывает bot.register_next_step_handler() telebot

Tags: python, telebot

Я хотел сделать так, чтобы у пользователя был выбор, добавить ли ему свои вопросы?

В случае, если да, то бот ему предлагал написать их. Он их занесет в базу данных, а потом можно будет посмотреть свой список вопросов.

Терминал ошибок не выдает

```
def choiceQuestions (message):
    #кнопка выбора
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup ()
    yesButton = types.KeyboardButton ("Да")
    noButton = types.KeyboardButton ("Нет")
    markup.row (yesButton, noButton)

    #сообщение перед кнопкой
    bot.send_message (message.chat.id, "Я имею базовые вопросы: \nКак дела? Что делаешь? \nКак спалось? Что снилось? \n\nНо вы можете добавить до пяти своих вопросов. Добавить?", reply_markup=markup)
    
    if message.text == "Да":
        bot.register_next_step_handler (message, dataBase)

def dataBase (message):

    conn = sqlite3.connect ("database.sql")
    cur = conn.cursor ()

    cur.execute ("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS questions (id int auto_increment primary key, question varchar (50), timee varchar (50))")

    conn.commit ()
    cur.close ()
    conn.close ()

def firstQuestion (message):
        global frstQue

        frstQue = message.text ()
        bot.send_message (message.chat.id, "Введи первый вопрос")
        bot.register_next_step_handler (message, secondQuestion)
```

Answer (score 1):

В `bot.register_next_step_handler()` вы должны передать сообщение с вопросом для пользования и 2-ым аргументом функцию для дальнейшей работы с полученными данными.

```
def choice_questions (message):
    #кнопка выбора
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
    yes_button = types.KeyboardButton("Да")
    no_button = types.KeyboardButton("Нет")
    markup.row(yes_button, no_button)

    #сообщение перед кнопкой
    sent = bot.send_message (message.chat.id, "Я имею базовые вопросы: \nКак дела? Что делаешь? \nКак спалось? Что снилось? \n\nНо вы можете добавить до пяти своих вопросов. Добавить?", reply_markup=markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler (sent, check_yes)

def check_yes(message):
    if message.text == "Да":
        database()
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ответ не да")

def database():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("database.sql")
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS questions (id int auto_increment primary key, question varchar (50), timee varchar (50))")

    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()

def first_question(message):
    global frst_que

    frst_que = message.text ()
    bot.send_message (message.chat.id, "Введи первый вопрос")
    bot.register_next_step_handler (message, second_question)
```

И ещё в питоне принято называть переменные/функции в таком формате: `this_is_var`, а не camelCase.